# Cannot install openshift cluster with htpasswd

Tags: macos, kubernetes, openshift

I successfully installed an opneshift cluster locally on my macOS, but `AllowAll identityProvider` is put by default, so I ran `oc cluster down` then `oc cluster up --http-proxy=gateway.docker.internal:3128 --https-proxy=gateway.docker.internal:3129 --base-dir="$HOME/.occluster" --write-config` and in the `master-config.yaml`for the kube-apiserver, openshift-apiserver and openshift-controller-manager I changed these values:

```
identityProviders:
- name: my_htpasswd_provider 
  challenge: true 
  login: true 
  mappingMethod: claim 
  provider:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider
    file: /etc/origin/master/htpasswd
```

When I run `oc cluster up` like before but without the `--write-config` flag I get the following:

```
I0513 12:45:46.901048   26313 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
E0513 12:50:47.962414   26313 run_self_hosted.go:571] API server error: Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: EOF ()
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

I cannot understand where is the mistake and what should be done in order to get rid of the errors

Comment: Hi, May I know how were you able to create an openshift Cluster "locally"?. Were you using minishift?.
From the error, It seems that your cluster is not responding that means your cluster is not up I believe. Can you check the status of your VMs where you have deployed the cluster?. Thanks

Comment: I did not use any VM, i just ran `oc cluster up` on mac

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not have the `htpasswd` file into the `kube-apiserver` folder. Putting it there managed to install the cluster with the specified `identityProvider`. Also, for logging in as `system:admin`, I had to run `export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/admin.kubeconfig"`. What am I looking forward is how to add more users to the cluster, because updating the `htpasswd` file is not the solution as I recall.